# Remove a parent based on child values

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following data structure

```
public class Prediction
{
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<MatchedSubstring> Matched_substrings { get; set; }
    public string Place_id { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public List<Term> Terms { get; set; }
    public List<string> Types { get; set; }
}

public class GooglePlaceAutocompleteResult
{
    public List<Prediction> Predictions { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is remove any items in the Predictions list if their Types collection contains the string "sublocality".

How can I do this with LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are writing a method within `GooglePlaceAutocompleteResult`, you can write:

```
Predictions = Predictions.Where(p => !p.Types.Any(t => t.Contains("sublocality")).ToList();
```

Otherwise the code would be the same but would be `result.Predictions = result.Predictions...`